# Roblox : Limit of simultaneous connected users in the same game / place

Tags: roblox

In Roblox, is there a limit of simultaneous connected users in one place or a game ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify the Game Settings for a Place, there is a setting for the Max Players, and that can be set to any amount. However, when I tried setting it to 500 players, it capped at 100.

In the past Roblox has experimented with 200 player servers, but it appears that it is currently capped at 100.

You can adjust this value through `Game Settings > Places > the three dots button > Max Players`.

[image]

Comment: Yes I saw that we can limit it in configs, but didn't know what would be the max. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits as far as I know but every place must contribute to the experience (They cannot be made with the sole purpose of hogging up server space).